# Align 1 child left, the rest right in a div

Tags: css, flexbox, alignment

Trying to align the 3 icons to the right while keeping the title positioned to the left:
[image]

Can't seem to get it to work. 
Justify-self: flex-end produced no result.
Margin-right: auto produced this:

[image]

CODE:

```
    <div className="nav-header-container">
      <span className="nav-header">TITLE</span>
      <img
        className="nav-header-icon"
        src="http://localhost:8000/static/frontend/icons/bell.svg/"
      />
      <img
        className="nav-header-icon"
        src="http://localhost:8000/static/frontend/icons/chat.svg/"
      />
      <img
        className="nav-header-icon"
        src="http://localhost:8000/static/frontend/icons/settings.svg/"
      />
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-header-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

  min-height: 4.26vh;
  width: 100%;

  padding-left: 1em;

  background-color: #435665;
}

.nav-header {
  font-family: open-sans, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.nav-header-icon {
  height: 20px;

  /* justify-self: flex-end; */
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: margin-right:auto to nav-header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the icons in a `div` then go `justify-content: space-between;`

html

```
 <div className="nav-header-container">
  <span className="nav-header">TITLE</span>
  <div class="nav-header-icons">
   <img
     className="nav-header-icon"
     src="http://localhost:8000/static/frontend/icons/bell.svg/"
   />
   <img
     className="nav-header-icon"
     src="http://localhost:8000/static/frontend/icons/chat.svg/"
   />
   <img
     className="nav-header-icon"
     src="http://localhost:8000/static/frontend/icons/settings.svg/"
   />
 </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.nav-header-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;

  min-height: 4.26vh;
  width: 100%;

  padding-left: 1em;

  background-color: #435665;
}

.nav-header-icons {
  padding-right: 1em;
}

.nav-header-icon {
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a div between title and icons (with class spacer on my example):

```
<div className="nav-header-container">
  <span className="nav-header">TITLE</span>
  <div className="spacer"></div>
  <img className="nav-header-icon" src="http://localhost:8000/static/frontend/icons/bell.svg/" />
  <img className="nav-header-icon" src="http://localhost:8000/static/frontend/icons/chat.svg/" />
  <img className="nav-header-icon" src="http://localhost:8000/static/frontend/icons/settings.svg/" />
</div>
```

And set it `flex:1` on your css rule:

```
.spacer{
   flex: 1
}
```